# Why does my script only run once on my humanoid/noob?

Tags: lua, roblox

Here is my code :

```
game.Workspace.Demons_Boss.Humanoid.Died:connect(function()
for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
v.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.MagesWin.Visible = true
v.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.DemonsWin.Visible = false
v.PlayerGui.SreenGui.MagesWin.LocalScript.Disabled = false
end
end)
```

I know my code only runs once because I tried to print something and it ran only once in the output. In the humanoid/noob model I also added a regen script. If you need my regen script it’s :

```
name = "Humanoid"

robo = script.Parent:Clone()

While true do
wait(3)
if script.Parent.Humanoid.Health <1 then
robot = robo:Clone()
robot.Parent = script.Parent.Parent
robot:MakeJoints()
script.Parent:remove()
wait(7)
local p = game.Players:GetChildren()
for i = 1,#p do
p[i].Character.Head:remove()
end
end
end
```

These two scripts are in two different scripts.

I really need help because I have been searching 1 month for the error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative solution would be :

```
game.Workspace,Demons_Boss.Humanoid.Died:connect(function()
```

should be

```
game.Workspace["Demons_Boss"].Humanoid.Died:connect(function()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a **,** after

> game.Workspace

instead of a **.** and if the humanoid dies and its character is deleted, the event is disconnected

Comment: To be really helpful, your answer should point out which `,` is wrong. Not just say something equivalent to "there is an error somewhere".

Comment: That was an error in my question. In my code I wrote game.Workspace.Demons_Boss.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code. At line 1, you typed a comma instead of a dot:

```
game.Workspace,Demons_Boss.Humanoid.Died:connect(function()
```

You should replace that line with:

```
workspace["Demons_Boss"].Humanoid.Died:connect(function()
```

Note that 'workspace' is equivalent to 'game.Workspace'.